# Sheaf restricted to Fibre

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the surface $S$  (therefore a $2$-dimensional, proper k-scheme) and 
$B$ irreducible curve (" $1$-dim " ).

Let $f: S \to B$ a proper fibration, so $\mathcal{O}_B= f_*\mathcal{O}_S$

Consider the unique generic point $\eta$ of $B$ and the generic fiber $f^{-1}(\eta)$.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be coherent sheaf on $S$ such that the restriction $\mathcal{F} \vert_{f^{-1}(\eta)}$ is invertible.

Why and how to prove that there exist an open subset $V \subset S$ with $f^{-1}(\eta) \subset V$ such that the restriction
$\mathcal{F} \vert_{V}$ is also invertible?

Remark by the way: I'm not sure if we need the fibration property for the statement below.

Comment: You should assume (for example) that $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent, else this is false. The properness is not important.

Comment: @Mohan: Yes, I fixed it. So then I know that it lies locally in ses ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {O}}_{X}^{\oplus I}|_{U}\to {\mathcal {O}}_{X}^{\oplus J}|_{U}\to {\mathcal {F}}|_{U}\to 0}$. It seems that this allows to reduce to the case that $\mathcal{F}$ is free, right? Can you give a hint how to cope with this case? Which open set $V \subset S$ might be an appropriate candidate?

Comment: Hint: Invertible $\Leftrightarrow$ locally free of rank 1, and the locus where a coherent sheaf is locally free is open.

Comment: @KReiser: ...and then you can argue by using the fact that locally rank is constant since it respects localisations (and we can work in affine case)? Just the point that the locus where a (coherent) sheaf is locally free is open isn't clear to me. We can again consider the affine case and we wan't to show that if $x \in X$ with $\mathcal{F}_{X,x}$ is free there exist open $U$ with $\mathcal{F} | _U$ free. I guess that the condition coherent is needed to apply  the classification theorem for finite generated modules. Then the statement is equivalent that locally there is no torsion.

Comment: But how to see this?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free at a point $x\in X$ iff there exists an open set $U_x$ containing $x$ so that $\mathcal{F}|_U\cong \mathcal{O}_U^n$ for some $n$. Additionally, $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free at all $u\in U$ by using the same $U$ and same isomorphism. The arbitrary union of open sets is open, so the union of all the $U_{x'}$ over all $x'$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free is open. This union is precisely the locus where $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free: it contains all the points where this happens, and every point in it satisfies the condition.

Comment: @KReiser: One other question that stayed unclear is following: 

The fiber $f^{-1}(\eta)= X_{\eta}$ is generally neither open nor closed set.
So for me the only meaningful way to interpret the restriction 
of $\mathcal{F}$ to $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is $\mathcal{F} | _{f^{-1}(\eta)}= 
\mathcal{F} \otimes k(\eta)$,right? So the thing is I'm not sure 
how to see from this that $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is contained in locally free locus of
$\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Obviously if $x \in X$ is contained in free locus then $\mathcal{F} \vert _{U_x}$
is free, so also $\mathcal{F} \otimes k(\eta) \vert _{U_x}$.
On the other hand there could maybe happen that $x \in X \cap f^{-1}(\eta)$ not belong to free locus, so
for all open $U \subset X$ with $x \in U$ the restriction $\mathcal{F} \vert _U$
isn't free, but the restriction $\mathcal{F} \otimes k(\eta) 
\vert _{U \cap f^{-1}(\eta)}$ possibly free. Or is this consideration wrong and the described case can't happen?

Comment: Additionally: Formally I think that the restriction $\mathcal{F} | _{f^{-1}(\eta)}$ 
can be defined as pullback $s^*\mathcal{F}$ for $s:X_{\eta} \to X$.
But here occurs the same problem with locally free locus:
Why does it hold for all $x \in f^{-1}(\eta)$: 

$$\exists V_x \subset f^{-1}(\eta): s^*\mathcal{F} \vert _{V_x} \text{is free} 
\Rightarrow \exists U_x \subset X: \mathcal{F} \vert _{U_x} \text{is free}$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general way of seeing this. Let a coherent sheaf be given as $\mathcal{O}_X^m\stackrel{\phi}{\to}\mathcal{O}_X^n\to F\to 0$. The set of points where $F$ is generated by at most r elements is open. Clearly, if $r\geq n$, then this is $X$ and hence open. So, assume $r<n$. The complement of points where $F$ needs more than $r$ generators can immediately seen to be the closed subset where all the $n-r\times  n-r$ minors of the matrix $\phi$ vanish and hence closed.